# Getting data from array doesn't work in for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, pdo

Fetching data to get array of ids i need

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT char_id FROM att WHERE raid_id=:id AND spec=:spec AND status=:status");
$STH->bindValue(":id", $id);
$STH->bindValue(":spec", $curr_spec);
$STH->bindValue(":status", $curr_status);
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$STH->execute();
$temp1 = $STH->fetchAll();
```

This code works perfectly. It returns correct values.

```
$temporary =$temp1[0]["char_id"];
echo $temporary;
```

But when i try to get values from array in this for loop it returns nothing in echo.

```
for($i=0; $i < 2; $i++)
{
$tempor =$temp1[i]["char_id"];
echo $tempor;

//...
}
```

I've spent a lot of time, but I couldn't solve it myself. If possible, please help me.

Comment: This is your entire code or there's codes between your `echo $temporary` and `for` statement?

Comment: You just forget the "$" before var name! $temp[$i]['char_id']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its not **i** change it to **$i**. You are accessing undefined constant and error_log would show you notice error.

```
$tempor =$temp1[i]["char_id"];

----------------^ change it to $i
```

**Tip:** instead of using **for** loop you could try using **foreach** loop and have a counter that will only loop for first 2 records.

Comment: And the OP will probably want to make sure `count($temp1) >= 2`

Comment: Ah, you're right. I feel embrassed. Should have seen it.

But it wasn't actually the point why I posted this question. I thought that was the point why my SQL syntax is wrong but it seems to be something else. I have such query:

    `$STH = $DBH->query("SELECT * FROM 'char' WHERE id=$tempor");
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "char");
    $curr_char = $STH->fetch();`

Comment: PHP Error says: `Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''char' WHERE id=2' at line 1' in /home/a9434194/public_html/raid.php:218 Stack trace: #0 /home/a9434194/public_html/raid.php(218): PDO->query('SELECT * FROM '...')`
'char' is one of my MySQL tables.